# Add Gesture Recognizer to specific UITabBarController tabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add a gesture recognizer to specific tabBar item's subview. I can successfully add one to the tabBar itself, but not a specific index.

I was able to trick it into reacting based on a `selectedIndex` by implementing this in my AppDelegate:

```
[self.tabBar.view addGestureRecognizer:longPressNotificationsGR];

-(void)showFilterForNotifications:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

  if (self.tabBar.selectedIndex == 4) {
      if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
          NSLog(@"Began");
      } else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
          NSLog(@"Ended");
      }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way? And yes I know this isn't what Apple had in mind but this is what I need for my particular project. I just feel like this isn't the best workaround, if there even is one, and i'm not sure how this will behave performance wide since its in the AppDelegate. But ultimately, I don't want to do it this way, I want to add it to the `objectAtIndex:n` so users can't just press and hold anywhere on the tabBar, even if 4 is the currently selected index. Right now users can tap & hold on index 1 icon, if 4 is selected, and the gesture methods get called. I want it to happen only if user is tapping & holding on `objectAtIndex:n`

Comment: Yes, you create an invisible UIView, you set this views frame to the tabbar's frame, you then create a mutalble array, store inside this array the touch location frames for each of the tabbar items you have, you then add a longpress gesture reognizer to the frame, you capture touch events. this touch events are handled by a filter than checks the point locations stored in the mutable array. the check that is performed is checking the set of touches to the location in view of the frames in the array, if it happens to be the frame you want, then you do work

Comment: Hmm. Seems like a tad more work then what I've already used as a work around. Thanks for the feedback though @Larcerax

Answer (score -1):

You can get the UIView of a tab at a specific index with the following category method on UITabBar:

```
- (UIView*)tabAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    BOOL validIndex = index < self.items.count;
    NSAssert(validIndex, @"Tab index out of range");
    if (!validIndex) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSMutableArray* tabBarItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.items count]];
    for (UIView* view in self.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITabBarButton")] && [view respondsToSelector:@selector(frame)]) {
            // check for the selector -frame to prevent crashes in the very unlikely case that in the future
            // objects that don't implement -frame can be subViews of an UIView
            [tabBarItems addObject:view];
        }
    }
    if ([tabBarItems count] == 0) {
        // no tabBarItems means either no UITabBarButtons were in the subView, or none responded to -frame
        // return CGRectZero to indicate that we couldn't figure out the frame
        return nil;
    }

    // sort by origin.x of the frame because the items are not necessarily in the correct order
    [tabBarItems sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UIView* view1, UIView* view2) {
        if (view1.frame.origin.x < view2.frame.origin.x) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        }
        if (view1.frame.origin.x > view2.frame.origin.x) {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        NSLog(@"%@ and %@ share the same origin.x. This should never happen and indicates a substantial change in the framework that renders this method useless.", view1, view2);
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }];

    if (index < [tabBarItems count]) {
        // viewController is in a regular tab
        return tabBarItems[index];
    }
    else {
        // our target viewController is inside the "more" tab
        return [tabBarItems lastObject];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Then, you just need to add your gesture recognizer:

```
[[self.tabBarController.tabBar tabAtIndex:4] addGestureRecognizer:myGestureRecognizer];
```